# proving that some transpose operator of the transpose operator is not injective.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces over $\mathbb k$ (where $\mathbb k$ could be $=\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$). Let $T\in L(X,Y) $ (a continuous and linear operator) then we define $T':Y'\to X'$ by $T'y'=y'T$.

I proved that if $T''$ is injective then $T$ it's injective. But I want to prove that the reciprocal it's not true following this example $T:c_0 \to c_0$ defined by $T(t_j)=(t_{j+1}-t_j)$ where $c_0$ is the set over $\mathbb k$.

$T$ it's clearly injective. I want to prove that $T''$ is not injective in a simple way. I proved that $Ker(T'')=Ann(Range(T'))$.

So if I prove that $Range(T')$ is dense then $Ann(Range(T'))=\{0\}$. But I can't do it.

Comment: The simplest way is to use $c_0' \cong \ell^1$ and $c_0'' \cong {\ell^1}' \cong \ell^\infty$, and find what $T''$ does when using the identification of $c_0''$ with $\ell^\infty$. It's patently obvious then that $T''$ isn't injective.

Comment: But it's also a lot of work, or not?

Comment: What is a lot of work? Proving that you have isometric isomorphisms $c_0' \cong \ell^1$ and ${\ell^1}' \cong \ell^\infty$? If you have already worked a bit with the spaces, that is probably less work than directly abstractly proving $\mathcal{R}(T')$ isn't dense.